# Add column to a file based on a sequential key on a third file (maybe with awk?)

Tags: text, awk, gawk, text-manipulation

I have a text file of the type:

file1.txt:

```
    > -L"200100"
    -6.37447846851  36.186032575
    -6.37383387763  36.1858844144
    -6.37377079559  36.1858390355
    > -L"200200"
    -6.31950329044  36.1191615625
    -6.31968900314  36.119114902
    -6.31908913286  36.1191091689
    > -L"200100"
    -6.31911178588  36.1188919898
    -6.31918479464  36.1188976987
    > -L"200250"
    -6.31909865128  36.1186432256
    -6.31920604922  36.1186522368
    -6.31941109375  36.1187126272
    ....
```

And a second text file like this:

file2.txt

```
    -51
    -14
    -101
    -32
    ...
```

I want that every time a row of the type '> -L"200100"' (actually any row starting by '> -L') is found on file1.txt a third column be appended taking the corresponding (sequential) value in file2.txt. In my example, the output would be:

file3.txt:

```
    > -L"200100"
    -6.37447846851  36.186032575  -51
    -6.37383387763  36.1858844144 -51
    -6.37377079559  36.1858390355 -51
    > -L"200200"
    -6.31950329044  36.1191615625 -14
    -6.31968900314  36.119114902  -14
    -6.31908913286  36.1191091689 -14
    > -L"200100"
    -6.31911178588  36.1188919898 -101
    -6.31918479464  36.1188976987 -101
    > -L"200250"
    -6.31909865128  36.1186432256 -32
    -6.31920604922  36.1186522368 -32
    -6.31941109375  36.1187126272 -32
    ....
```

The number of '> -L' occurrences file1.txt equals the same number of rows in file2.txt.

Is that possible with an awk/gawn oneliner?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

give this one-liner a try:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{k[NR]=$0;next}/^>/{++i;print;next}{print $0,k[i]}' f2 f1
```

with your data, here the above line gives:

```
kent$  awk 'NR==FNR{k[NR]=$0;next}/^>/{++i;print;next}{print $0,k[i]}' f2 f1
> -L"200100"
-6.37447846851  36.186032575 -51
-6.37383387763  36.1858844144 -51
-6.37377079559  36.1858390355 -51
> -L"200200"
-6.31950329044  36.1191615625 -14
-6.31968900314  36.119114902 -14
-6.31908913286  36.1191091689 -14
> -L"200100"
-6.31911178588  36.1188919898 -101
-6.31918479464  36.1188976987 -101
> -L"200250"
-6.31909865128  36.1186432256 -32
-6.31920604922  36.1186522368 -32
-6.31941109375  36.1187126272 -32
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty easily in Perl if you save this as "Append3rdCol" and then do:

```
chmod +x Append3rdCol
./Append3rdCol
```

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $extra;
open(F1,"file1.txt") or die;
open(F2,"file2.txt") or die;
while(<F1>){
   chomp;           # Strip line ending
   if(m/^>/){               # If line starts with ">"
      print "$_\n";
      chomp($extra=readline(*F2));  # Read next line of file2 and trim <CR>
   } else {
      print "$_  $extra\n";
   }
}
```